# Discern a specific plugin's action hooks

Tags: plugins, login, actions

I'm new to Wordpress plugin development (but not to coding) so please excuse the question.

I am trying to develop a plugin to catch user registrations and populate other web application databases from this (I have phpBB + Mantis Bug Tracker in my main domain alongside Wordpress). It will populate the mysql databases form the wordpress registration/password change etc.

I am using "UsersWP" as my main user manager. It advertises that it has lots of hooks to offer extensibility. However, I can't seem to discern how to leverage these hooks. Sadly, there's no documentation with he plugin where they list the action hooks/filters.

I downloaded the sourcecode from [here](https://github.com/UsersWP/userswp) and did a search for `action_do` There were a number of results, but most don't get caught by my plugin code. I tried `wp_login` (this is referneced in the UsersWP code) but this doesn't return anything. However, the UsersWP specific action hook `uwp_loaded` does get caught. My code:

```
<?php

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) or die( 'No script kiddies please!' );

// Log File ==========================================================
function write_log ($txt) {
    $myfile = fopen("stigzler-log.txt", "a") or die("Unable to open file!");
    fwrite($myfile,  "\n". date('h:i:s ', time()) . $txt);
    fclose($myfile);
}

/* NULL RESULT: */
function ogz_SettingsSaved() {
    write_log('Settings saved');
}
add_action('uwp_settings_save_','ogz_SettingsSave');

/* NULL RESULT: */
function ogz_wp_login( $user_login, $user ) {
    write_log('wp_login: ' . $user_login);
}
add_action('wp_login', 'ogz_wp_login', 10, 2);

/* GETS RESULT: */
function ogz_uwp_loaded() {
    write_log('uwp_loaded triggered');
}
add_action('uwp_loaded', 'ogz_uwp_loaded');

?>
```

Hopefully someone can give a me a steer towards how I achieve what I'm looking to achieve.

UPDATE:

Following a comment, tried some differetn hooks. HOwever, whilst `uwp_Loaded fires`, neither `uwp_after_process_register` nor `uwp_after_process_login` do. IS there something wrong with my code?

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Signup Sync (OGZ)
 * Plugin URI: http://www.mywebsite.com/my-first-plugin
 * Description: Syncs other databases on signup
 * Version: 1.0
 * Author: stigzler
 * Author URI: http://www.magoarcade.org
 */

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) or die( 'No script kiddies please!' );

// Log File ==========================================================
function write_log ($txt) {
    $myfile = fopen("stigzler-log.txt", "a") or die("Unable to open file!");
    fwrite($myfile,  "\n". date('h:i:s ', time()) . $txt);
    fclose($myfile);
}

function ogz_uwp_loaded() {
    write_log('uwp_loaded triggered');  
    }
add_action('uwp_loaded', 'ogz_uwp_loaded');

function ogz_uwp_after_process_register( $data, $user_id ) {
    $user_info = get_userdata($user->ID);
    write_log('uwp_after_process_register: ' . "\r" . $user_info->user_login . "/r" . $user_info->ID);
}
add_action('uwp_after_process_register', 'ogz_uwp_after_process_register', 10, 2);

function ogz_uwp_after_process_login() {
    write_log('uwp_after_process_login triggered');
}
add_action('uwp_after_process_login', 'ogz_uwp_after_process_login');

?>
```

Comment: They list a number of hooks here: https://userswp.io/support/topic/hook-after-user/ - looks like `uwp_after_process_register` may be what you're looking for.

Comment: @WebElaine - thanks! I'm starting to wonder whether it's my code. See the update in the OP. The author of the link you sent appears to have gotten `uwp_after_process_register` working. However, it doesn't work in my code - I'm starting to think it's my code.

Comment: It's always best to start very simple. Hook into the hook you're targeting, and just output text to a file, or something simple like that. When that works, add complexity, a little at a time.